# Checkmarks not working in a tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my iOS app, I have a tableView and when you click on the cell, a checkmark shows up. When you click on the cell again though, the checkmark doesn't do away. I have checked my code over and over again. These are the two methods that have to do with `UITableViewAccessoryCheckmark`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

PFUser *user = [self.allUsers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = user.username;

if ([self isFriend:user]) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}

return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

PFRelation *friendsRelation = [self.currentUser relationforKey:@"friendsRelation"];
PFUser *user = [self.allUsers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if ([self isFriend:user]) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    for(PFUser *friend in self.friends) {
        if ([friend.objectId isEqualToString:user.objectId]) {
            [self.friends removeObject:friend];
            break;
        }
    }

    [friendsRelation removeObject:user];
}
else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    [self.friends addObject:user];
    [friendsRelation addObject:user];
}

[self.currentUser saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
}
```

Can someone please post the correct code? Thank you!

Comment: My bad, can you post some code of `[self isFriend:user]`??

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the accessory view [property on UITableViewCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/accessoryView) to nil.

```
cell.accessoryView = nil;
```

Comment: it does the exact same thing